# Basic Charging with Java Diameter client

Tags: java, diameter-protocol, jbilling

I am newbie to diameter protocol and its implementation in Java. I have done some basic R&D on Diameter protocol,its interface AAA etc and stuff. 
My Objective is to create a simple application for a client , which can charge to customer at some specific event.

So can anybody help me that, is it possible, any library available in java , if possible any example stuff.

Really thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to charge customer at an event, you can simply use jBilling for it. Diameter is required only when the event requires session management.

Feel free to explain the requirement and Diameter specifications you'd want to adhere to.

Thanks
Vikas